# Efficient pane switching in tmux

Tags: tmux

When switching panes in `tmux` using ^B and cursor keys, what is the quickest way to get out of pane-switching mode and return input handling to the program in the pane?

For instance, you just switched to the shell in your left pane with ^B and Left, and now you want to press Up and Enter to repeat the shell's last command, except `tmux` steals the Up keypress thinking you're still switching panes.

There has to be a key combo or something to finish pane switching, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split pane switching in tmux: switch once per command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668633/split-pane-switching-in-tmux-switch-once-per-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because pressing arrows is "expensive" keystroke with my keyboard, I  hardly use arrow keys.

My vim has `ctrl-h,j,kl` to switch windows, so I defined in tmux `prefix h,j,k,l` to switch panes. (my prefix is `ctrl-a`)

For commandline editing, I don't use any arrow keys either, instead, I use ctrl/alt heavily, my ctrl key is at a good position to press. so re-run last command, I press ctrl-p, enter.

Using ctrl/alt to edit commandline is fast and convenient, since you don't leave your home row.

```
ctrl-p last cmd
ctrl-h backspace
ctrl-a first col
ctrl-d del current char
ctrl-e eol
ctrl-w remove word backwards
ctrl-b/f back/forward
alt-b/f back/forward a word
alt-d remove word forward
there are a lot more... like ctrl-k, ctrl-u, ctrl-y, alt-. etc.
```

And if I need edit a really long and complex command, I do `ctrl-x ctrl-e`, and edit it in my vim.

Comment: I am going to try using `ctrl-i,j,k,l` for changing tmux panes, as I rarely have several windows in a vim session. Can imagine that using cursor keys to switch between vim windows would feel natural. Thanks for all the good ideas!

Comment: @tripflag ok. just try it. my keyboard doesn't have cursor keys. well it does,  but I have to press `Fn` + some keys to do cursor moving (arrows+home/end/pgup/pgdn etc)

Comment: use ctrl-a as prefix I lost "ctrl-a first col" for my commandline editing inside tmux though